# can't install psycopg2 on centos

Tags: python, centos, odoo, centos5

I use `pip` and `easy_install`.

I got this error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2

Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

running egg_info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/psycopg2

Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Really need your help guys..

Answer (score 10):

Edited: I read that as 'pgconfig', and not 'pyconfig' the first time around.

If you are missing `pyconfig.h`, then you probably are missing the **Python** development packages.

Try to `yum install python-devel` and then install psycopg2 again.

(You'll still need the `postgresql-devel` package as well, if you don't have that installed)

Comment: i did it. but when i was trying to look in /usr/include/python2.6, there is no folder python2.6.
i only have python2.6 folder in /usr/bin/, what should i do?

Comment: See the edit to this post; it's not postgresql-devel that you're likely missing, but python-devel.

Comment: JUST INSTALL      "yum install postgresql-devel" AND TRY REINSTALLING PSYCOPG2 AGAIN